# crystal Reports printing blank page if odd Page count in Group

Tags: crystal-reports

I have Cristal Reports 13.0 I need to reset page number for every new group, and if group contains odd number of pages need to add blank page, if there is even number of pages nothing should be done just reset page numbers. I found many issues about this but nothing works as it should. There is Group Header 1 anf Group Footer 1, and report need to be printed on duplex printer. Thanks

Comment: You will need a formula to count pages for you, since you need to reset the counter. You will probably have to declare a variable to do it. Furthermore, you need to use it in section expert to set when you will insert a "new page before" the section. Try something like that and let me now what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert an empty Group Footer section, so you will have Group Footer 1a and 1b.
2. In section Expert, in Group Footer 1a; check "New Page After" checkbox.
   Also check "Reset Page Number After" and add formula by clicking the box next to it.

   `if PageNumber mod 2 =0 then true else false`
3. In section Expert, in Group Footer 1b; check "New Page After" and  "Reset Page Number After" checkbox.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. it is working fine...Problem is i have 4 group header and footer. In last footer section i have added this above steps...It concatenates  Page Number for 2 different grroup ids. For eg Group 1 has  4 Page  and Group  2  has 4 page it merges 2 group and shows as  Total Page 8... I have issues with page Number reseting